A "proof" of negative variance
In trying to solve the problem below, I got a negative variance. What is the error in this "false proof" of negative variance? And why does it produce the correct variance times $-1$?

Let $X$ be the number of distinct birthdays in a group of $n = 110$ people. Assuming birthdays are IID Uniform over $y = 365$ days, find the mean and variance of $X$.

Note: Alternate solutions to this problem exist.  This question asks to find the error in this line of argument.

Let $X$ be the total number of distinct birthdays, and let $I_j$ indicate if the group has a birthday on day $j$.  For shorthand, write $\alpha := \frac{y-1}{y}$.  Then $$
X = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq y} I_j \\
I_j \sim \text{Bern}(p) \\
q = \alpha^n \\
p= 1 - q.
$$
Recall that $$\text{Var}(X) = \sum_{\substack{1 \leq j \leq y \\ 1 \leq k \leq y}}\text{Cov}(I_j,I_k).$$
For $j = k, \text{Cov}(I_j, I_k) = pq$.  For $j \neq k$, we have
$$
\text{Cov}(I_j, I_k) = E[I_jI_k] - EI_jEI_k \\
E[I_jI_k] = P(I_j = 1, I_k = 1) \\
= 1 - 2P(I_j = 1, I_k = 0) - P(I_j = 0, I_k = 0) \\
P(I_j = 0, I_k = 0) = \left( \frac{y-2}{y} \right)^n \\
= \left(\alpha - \frac{1}{y} \right)^n \\
P(I_j = 1, I_k = 0) = p \alpha^{n-1}.
$$
The last line, $P(I_j = 1, I_k = 0) = p \alpha^{n-1}$, is proven as follows:

We must have at least one person with birthday $j$. This is probability $p$.
Put the tallest person with birthday $j$ aside.  The other $n - 1$ people can have any birthday (even $j$) except $k$.  This has probability $\alpha^{n-1}$.

Putting this altogether, we get
$$\text{Var}(X) = ypq + y(y-1)\left[ 1 - 2p\alpha^{n-1} - \left(\alpha - \frac 1 y \right)^n - p^2\right] \\
\approx -10.019
$$
which is obviously incorrect, because variance can't be negative.
Strangely, sources list the variance as $\approx +10.019$.
What is the error in the "proof", and why does it produce the true variance $\cdot -1$?

Downvoter: math.SE works best if people explain what other information they need or revisions they suggest.  A random down/close vote doesn't help anyone learn.

The mistake is your calculation of $P[I_j=1,I_k=0]$. This is more easily computed by $P[I_k=0]P[I_j=1|I_k=0]$. You are attempting to compute it as $P[I_j=1]P[I_k=0|I_k=1]$ and your $P[I_k=0|I_k=1]$ is incorrect.

The mistake is in the following argument:

The last line, $P(I_j = 1, I_k = 0) = p \alpha^{n-1}$, is proven as follows:

We must have at least one person with birthday $j$. This is probability $p$.
Put the tallest person with birthday $j$ aside.  The other $n - 1$ people can have any birthday (even $j$) except $k$.  This has probability $\alpha^{n-1}$.


The problem with "putting the tallest person with birthday $j$ aside" is that now, the probability of nobody else having birthday $k$ is muddled. Specifically, the probability of not having birthday $k$ is $\alpha = \frac{y-1}{y}$ for everyone shorter than the person we put aside, but $\frac{y-2}{y-1}$ for everyone taller: we know those people don't have birthday $j$, so they are limited to $y-1$ possible birthdays! If we really want to approach the problem this way, we must say:

The probability that the person we put aside is the $i^{\text{th}}$ tallest person is $\alpha^{i-1}(1-\alpha)$: the probability that the first $i-1$ people do not have birthday $j$, but the $i^{\text{th}}$ does.
In this scenario, the probability that nobody else has birthday $k$ is $(\frac{y-2}{y-1})^{i-1} \alpha^{n-i}$.
To find the overall probability that $I_j=1$ and $I_k=0$, we multiply these and sum over all $i$, getting $$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha^{i-1}(1-\alpha)\left(\frac{y-2}{y-1}\right)^{i-1} \alpha^{n-i}.$$

After some work, this simplifies to the correct formula: $P(I_j=1,I_k=0) = \alpha^n - (\alpha-\frac1y)^n$. (We get more or less the sum above by factoring this as a difference of $n^{\text{th}}$ powers.) The shorter argument for the formula $\alpha^n - (\alpha - \frac1y)^n$ is that $P(I_j=1,I_k=0)$ can be found as $P(I_k=0) - P(I_j=0,I_k=0)$.

There's still some remaining mystery: why does this mistake give us the exact negative of the variance?
If $p_{01} = P(I_j=1, I_k=0) = \alpha^n - (\alpha - \frac1y)^n$, and $f_{01} = p\alpha^{n-1}$, then the difference between the true and false covariance is exactly $2(p_{01}-f_{01})$. Therefore, in order for the coincidence to happen, $2y(y-1)(f_{01}-p_{01})$ must give us exactly $2 \cdot \text{Var}(X)$. After playing around with this expression for a bit, I don't have a better explanation for this than coincidental cancellation.


The last line, $P(I_j = 1, I_k = 0) = p \alpha^{n-1}$, is proven as follows:

We must have at least one person with birthday $j$. This is probability $p$.
Put the tallest person with birthday $j$ aside.  The other $n - 1$ people can have any birthday (even $j$) except $k$.  This has probability $\alpha^{n-1}$.


Error spotted.
$p$ is the probability that a particular person (say "Fred") has the selected birthday (day $j$). $~\alpha^{n-1}$ is the probability that $n-1$ other people do not have another selected birthday (day $k$, when $j\neq k$).
So, you appear to be claiming that $\mathsf P(I_j=1,I_k=0)$ equals $\mathsf P(\text{Fred}=j)\cdot\mathsf P(I_j=1,I_k=0\mid \text{Fred}=j)$ , which it does not.  The Law of Total Probability mandates that :
$$\mathsf P(I_j{\,=\,}1,I_k{\,=\,}0)~~{\large=}~~p\,\alpha^{n-1}+(1-p)\,\mathsf P(I_j{,=\,}1,I_k{\,\neq\,}0\mid \text{Fred}{\,=\,}j)\tag{when $j\neq k$}$$
And that last factor will be recursively defined by this method, so I do not suggest using it. (It's possible, but messy.)

Rather, just evaluate $\mathsf P(I_j{\,=\,}1,I_k{\,=\,}0)=\mathsf P(I_j{\,=\,}1\mid I_k=0)\cdot\mathsf P(I_k{\,=\,}0)$
Where $\mathsf P(I_j{\,=\,}1\mid I_k=0)$ is the probability that some among the $n$ are born on day $j$ given that none are born on day $k$.  Which is $1-((y-2)/(y-1))^n$.

Let $X$ be the total number of distinct birthdays, and let $I_j$ indicate if the group has a birthday on day $j$.  For shorthand, write $\alpha := \frac{y-1}{y}$.  Then for all $j,k~\in[[1,y]]$

$$\begin{align}
 X &:= \sum_{1 \leq j \leq y} I_j\\
q &:=\mathsf P(I_j=0) \\
  &\: = \alpha^n \\
p &:= 1 - q \\&= (y^n-(y-1)^n)/y^n
\\\therefore\quad I_j &\sim \text{Bern}(p) 
\\ \mathsf P(I_j=0,I_k=0) &=\begin{cases}((y-1)/y)^n&:& j=k\\((y-2)/y)^n&:&j\neq k\end{cases}\\
\mathsf P(I_j=1,I_k=0) &=\mathsf P(I_j=1\mid I_k=0)\,\mathsf P(I_k=0)\\&=\begin{cases}0 &:& j=k\\(1-((y-2)/(y-1))^n)\,((y-1)/y)^n&:& j\neq k\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}0 &:& j=k\\((y-1)^n-(y-2)^n)/y^n&:& j\neq k\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
So, assigning $\beta:=(y-2)/y$ we have
$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Cov}(I_j,I_k) &= \mathsf P(I_j=1,I_k=1)-\mathsf P(I_j=1)\mathsf P(I_k=1)\\&=\begin{cases}1-\alpha^n-(1-\alpha^n)^2 &:& j=k\\1-2(\alpha^n-\beta^n)-\beta^{n}-(1-\alpha^n)^2&:&j\neq k\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}\alpha^n-\alpha^{2n} &:& j=k\\\beta^{n}-\alpha^{2n}&:&j\neq k\end{cases}\\\mathsf{Var}(X)&=y(\alpha^n-\alpha^{2n})+y(y-1)(\beta^n-\alpha^{2n})\\&=y(\alpha^n-\beta^n)-y^2(\alpha^{2n}-\beta^n)\\&\approx 10.01{\small 9}\end{align}$$

I can't agree with the claim that "$p$ is the probability that a particular person... has the selected birthday (day $j$)".  Since $p = 1 - q$, it is the complement of "no one has birthday $j$", and therefore the probability that at least one person has birthday $j$.
